# How to filter stopwords for spaCy tokenized text contained in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spacy

I am trying to apply some spaCy NLP functions to texts contained in a pandas dataframe. For simple processes, a `lambda` function seems to work. However, when trying to perform tasks that require more complex statements defined in a separate function I am struggling to make the `lambda` method work properly. **Specifically, for spaCy tokenized text contained in a dataframe, what is the best way to filter out stopwords?** My example below seeks to filter and return non-stopwords. I plan to extend that to other spaCy tags, but am trying to work out the method using the `token.is_stop` attribute.

### Minimal Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import spacy

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['This is the first text. It is two sentences.',
    'This is the second text, with one sentence.']})

# check dataframe
# df

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# create new col and fill with tokenized text
df['Tokens'] = ''
doc = df['Text']
doc = doc.apply(lambda x:
                nlp(x)
               )
df['Tokens'] = doc
# check dataframe
# df

# Confirming that the text is tokenized
doc = df.loc[0,'Tokens']
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

When I try to filter stopwords using a `lambda` function, it returns the error `AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'is_stop'`

### Erroneous Code:

```
# Seeking to apply filter to tokens
def filter_stopwords(text):
    tokens_no_stop = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
    return tokens_no_stop

df['No Stopwords'] = ''
doc = df['Tokens']
doc = doc.apply(lambda x:
               filter_stopwords(x)
              )
df['No Stopwords'] = doc
```

What is the best way to approach things like filtering stopwords or POS and passing the result to a new column? **I think I'm not properly accessing the spacy object, but not sure how to.** Thank you in advance.

Comment: your lambda function needs an input. `lambda doc: ....`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on what the input statement should look like? If I put `x=` in front of `[token...` it returns the error `lambda cannot contain assignment`. Besides, that's an assignment statement and not an input as you suggest. The only way I know to filter stopwords, etc is to assign it to a variable as in the examples above. However, lambda it seems does not permit assignment. How should one call the input? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, *given some of the restrictions on lambda functions is there a better way to approach the issue?* 'lambda' works for fairly simple statements, but when they become more complex I've asked myself if it makes more sense to define a function separately with `def` and pass that to `lambda`. While that approach occurred to me, I'm not sure how to implement it or if it is a good idea at all.

Comment: Thanks, I see how I needed to have lambda input. I fixed that issue and am now getting a new error. I modified the question to have lambda input and report the new error which I think is related to how I'm trying to access a spaCy doc object.

Comment: In general with spaCy, you **don't** need to manually process stopwords, because [the stages in the pipeline already implement that, most noteably Tokenizer](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines). See [this](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#language-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Filter stopwords and load back into dataframe.

```
# Define a function, create a column, and apply the function to it
def remove_stops(tokens):
    return [token.text for token in tokens if not token.is_stop]
df['No Stop'] = df['Tokens'].apply(remove_stops)
```

## Result

[image]

## Generalizable

The method can be generalized to other functions where appropriate for longer documents.

```
def nouns_filtered(tokens):
    return [token.text for token in tokens if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop and token.pos_ == 'NOUN']
df['Filtered Nouns'] = df['Tokens'].apply(nouns_filtered)


def verbs_filtered(tokens):
    return [token.text for token in tokens if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop and token.pos_ == 'VERB']
df['Filtered Verbs'] = df['Tokens'].apply(verbs_filtered)

def adjectives_filtered(tokens):
    return [token.text for token in tokens if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop and token.pos_ == 'ADJ']
df['Filtered Adjectives'] = df['Tokens'].apply(adjectives_filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix it for you ?

```
def filter_stopwords(text):
    # this will ;
    #    - apply spacy to the text 
    #    - create one list of tokens without stop words
    tokens_no_stop = [word.text for sentence in nlp(text) for word in sentence if not word.is_stop]

    return tokens_no_stop

df['No Stopwords'] = df['Text'].apply(filter_stopwords)
```

Comment: For me, this returns the error `TypeError: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' object is not iterable`. If I read the error correctly, this has moved things forward as your code accesses the tokens whereas what I had accesses the doc. I appreciate your giving this consideration.